# Storing text value entered in screen flow to update record in flow

Tags: screen-flow

I have a screen flow setup to capture contract cancellation details.
[image]

In the screen flow I need to first populate the current text values from the contract record in the text field in the screen flow. Users then will update the text value. How do I pass the updated text value the User entered in the screen into the Update Record action? I have created a variable(varPreviousValues) to obtain the current text values and populate the values in the screen and this is working as expected.
[image]

[image]

Users then update the text value in the screen for the fields to be updated.
[image]

In my Update Record action I have referenced the Screen Flow value.

[image]

However, when I process the cancellation the values entered by the User through the screen are not populating. The record is populated with the original text values.
[image]

Comment: How are you assigning the previous value of the input fields? Are you using default value for each element? I've tried this and it works for me.

Comment: I'm assigning the previous values through collection variable pulling the data from the previous opportunity. Also when I debug the flow the record shows it will be updated correctly. But when I process the record through the ui the fields don't update as expected.

Comment: I figured this out. In our SF region we had another flow that was populating the value back as the original values. Once this flow was updated the values are remaining.

Comment: It's a screen flow - how was a another flow involved with this?